# Comments box acting unexpected

Tags: facebook, comments

I am tring to implement the comments box into my website, providing the following code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=204934639590323";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://my_web.com/" data-num-posts="2" data-width="500"></div>
```

When i post a message into the comments box, that message is not posted onto my wall. Also, when i logout from fb, that message dissapers. Hope to give me some ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you logout of Facebook and then the comment disappears it seems a privacy configuration on your account, that's why when you become anonymous Facebook hides the comment.

Also, if the comment is not posted (despite you check you want this behavior on the comment box) maybe your app is in sandbox mode OR again you have specific configurations for this app.

To quickly have a better idea of what is going on you could ask someone else to comment.

Hope that helps.